# determining hashing function

Tags: algorithm, hash

Hi I have several inputs and several outputs. I pass an ID to a third party and they hash the ID i submitted. Now i want to know what function was used so i can compare my id to the hashed verion however don't know how they generated their id from mine.

input is always bigint containg 19 integers
output is alpahnumric containing 16 values which seem to always begin with an integer.

What i am asking may sound strange as its like having a mathametical equation with operands and answer and asking what function was applied. However because i have a large data set of inputs and corresponding outputs i can eliminate the functions which don't hold true for all cases.

Also if i pass the same id twice they generate the same corresponding id, which leads me to the conclusion time seeding was not used

So how do i go about writing a script to determine the function is my question? If its even possible?

Comment: With the information provided, no, it's not possible.

Comment: what extra information do you recon i need?

Comment: You would need a description of the hash function. Have you tried asking the "third party"? Failing that, you can know the value of the function for every id you have already hashed, by storing each (id, hash) pair in a database.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use any of the standard hashing functions and see if it fits.  MD5, SHA or others.  But even if a standard one was used, it might have been seeded or encrypted.

So my answer is, you probably cant determine the hashing function.

Comment: thanks i tried several of the more popular ones and trunctaed the ones with longer outputs than i required. I find it frustrating that given the large number of inputs and outputs i have i cannot write a script that finds the link between them. As if i pass on the same id they generate the same corresponding id.